# Sum column in the same hour together and if there is no record for that hour, store value as 0

Tags: sql

Say I have a table with these records:

```
Date                    |Instances
2015-10-12 06:15:00.000 |2   
2015-10-12 06:45:00.000 |5
2015-10-12 04:15:00.000 |2
2015-10-12 04:25:00.000 |3
2015-10-12 03:15:00.000 |5
2015-10-12 02:15:00.000 |6
2015-10-12 01:15:00.000 |6
```

I manage to sum all instance in the same hour together with the following query:

```
  SELECT DATEPART(HOUR,DATE) as TIMEHOUR,
         SUM([INSTANCES]) as INSTANCESUM
  FROM TABLE (NOLOCK) 
  where DATE BETWEEN DATEADD(HOUR, -5, GETUTCDATE()) AND GETUTCDATE() 
  group by DATEPART(HOUR, DATE)
  order by DATEPART(HOUR, DATE) DESC
```

The result is something like this:

```
TIMEHOUR | INSTANCESUM
6        | 7
4        | 5
3        | 5
2        | 6
1        | 6
```

But I need the hour to record the instancesum as 0 if there is none. Say the UTC Time is 06:00 the table will return something like this:

```
     TIMEHOUR | INSTANCESUM
     6        | 7
---> 5        | 0 <---
     4        | 5
     3        | 5
     2        | 6
     1        | 6
```

Is it possible on ms sql?

[EDIT]

What I need is that the result table will always have the same amount of entry depending on the time range I set. So even if there is no record in that time range, the result table still have that number of record, just with 0 as value

```
TIMEHOUR | INSTANCESUM
6        | 0
5        | 0
4        | 0
3        | 0
2        | 0
1        | 0
```

Comment: A followup question: is there a way to display TIMEHOUR as a DATETIME format yyyy-mm-dd hh?

Comment: Shouldn't it be *DATE* in place of *TIMEHOUR* in group by and order by? Looks like it's a typo.

Comment: @vnikhil Yes that is a typo. Thanks for pointing that out

Comment: You need a tally table supplying all needed values (1 to 24?). Than you can use this in FROM and LEFT JOIN your data.

Answer (score 0):

See the code below:

```
declare @temp table (timehour int, instancesum int)
insert into @temp values (6,7), (4,5), (3,5), (2,6), (1,6) -- Replace values with your original query.

select timehour, instancesum from @temp
union
select l.timehour + 1 as timehour, 0
from 
    @temp as l
    left join @temp as r on l.timehour + 1 = r.timehour
where 
    l.timehour < (select max(timehour) from @temp) and 
    r.timehour is null
```

Output:

```
timehour    instancesum
1           6
2           6
3           5
4           5
5           0
6           7
```

I tried this in MS-SQL since I have not worked on MySQL. However most logic would remain same. The only part I am not sure about is creating @temp temporary table in MySQL. If you can alter that part (if required) you are good.

Answer (score 0):

To answer the original question, you could left join the table to itself on the equal hour and the instances that don't appear during an hour in the left join should report their sum as null, you could then apply an nvl treatment to output 0 as their sum. Something like this:

```
 SELECT
DATEPART(t.HOUR,t.DATE) as TIMEHOUR
, nvl(SUM([ti.INSTANCES]), 0) as INSTANCESUM

FROM TABLE (NOLOCK) as t
left join TABLE  as ti
on 
DATEPART(t.HOUR,t.DATE) = 
DATEPART(ti.HOUR,ti.DATE)

where
DATE BETWEEN DATEADD(HOUR, -5, GETUTCDATE()) AND GETUTCDATE() 
 
group by
DATEPART(HOUR, DATE)
order by
DATEPART(HOUR, DATE) DESC
```

To answer your second question in the comments:

You should be able to output the date time in any format you want using

```
To_char(date, 'yyyymmdd hh:mm:ss')
```

At least that's what would work in Oracle, MySQL syntax may be slightly different.

Comment: Do you know the mssql version of this? Cant get it to work

Comment: What's the error you're getting? That was all interested air code, so it may have syntax issues, but conceptually it should work.